# How to call a function in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to call a function in TextInput onChangeText but I am getting this error: Unexpected token, expected ";" (17:13).

Line no 17 is getUsers () {

My code is

```
getUsers () {
    alert('hi');
}

return (
    ....
    <TextInput onChangeText={this.getUsers}></TextInput>
    ....
)
```

Comment: Post the entire file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `getUsers` as an arrow function.

```
getUsers = () => {
alert('Hi');
}
```

And after that can call like

```
<TextInput onChangeText={()=>this.getUsers()}></TextInput>
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will be help for you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  View, TextInput, } from 'react-native';
export default class MyClass extends Component {

    getUsers = () => {
        alert('hi');
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >

        <TextInput onChangeText={()=>this.getUsers()}></TextInput>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code

```
class Home extends React.Component {

getUsers =()=> {
        alert('hi');
    }
    render(){
    return (
        ....
        <TextInput onChangeText={this.getUsers}></TextInput>
        ....
    )
    }


}
```

this should work,  feel free for doubts